# How to get links to all video formats for Youtube video

Tags: video, youtube

I working with Youtube api to search videos. I have some links to video (like this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hls5fuQm658). I can get video id from it (hls5fuQm658).

Youtube has few different video formats for each video (low-res mp4 for mobile phones, high-res mp4 for PC, etc).

My question is the next - how to get links to all possible video formats for video by given id (hls5fuQm658, for example)?

Thanks!